# IF syntax error in python

Tags: python

I have an error in the if syntax

```
if(m.distance&lt;0.75*n.distance):
```

- I am doing project on image processing

Code:

```
while True:

    ret, QueryImgBGR=cam.read()
    QueryImg=cv2.cvtColor(QueryImgBGR,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    queryKP,queryDesc=detector.detectAndCompute(QueryImg,None)
    matches=flann.knnMatch(queryDesc,trainDesc,k=2)
    goodMatch=[]

    for m,n in matches:
         if(m.distance&lt;0.75*n.distance):
             goodMatch.append(m)

    if(len(goodMatch)&gt;MIN_MATCH_COUNT):
        tp=[]
        qp=[]

        for m in goodMatch:
            tp.append(trainKP[m.trainIdx].pt)
            qp.append(queryKP[m.queryIdx].pt)
        tp,qp=np.float32((tp,qp))
        H,status=cv2.findHomography(tp,qp,cv2.RANSAC,3.0)
        h,w=trainImg.shape
        trainBorder=np.float32([[[0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0]]])
        queryBorder=cv2.perspectiveTransform(trainBorder,H)
        cv2.polylines(QueryImgBGR,[np.int32(queryBorder)],True,(0,255,0),5)
    else:
        print "Not Enough match found- %d/%d"%(len(goodMatch),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)

    cv2.imshow('result',QueryImgBGR)
    if cv2.waitKey(10)==ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Give a space if <space> condition:

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Please also check and mention whether you are using *Python2* or *Python3*. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

semi colon is used to terminate statements, which when present in your if statement terminates it. It is normally used to write multiple statements on same line like `a=1;print a;c=3;`